# ERC20 exchange support

Tags: erc-20, exchanges

how can you add support for erc20 tokens on your own exchange, so that users can perform transactions between themselves? There are many services that make it possible to work with BTC and ETH, but there is no information how to work with ERC20 tokens

Comment: Trading tokens on exchange is not any different from trading other assets.  What is different is deposit, withdraw, and holding tokens.  Could you add more details to your questions about what do you have already, what do you want to have, what did you try, and what obstacles did you encounter?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Судя по нику, вы русский, так думаю будет проще, суть в том, что я не знаю как добавить возможность заводить/выводить, проводить транзакции между пользователями токенами ERC20. Кто-то пишет, что нужно поднимать свою ноду эфириума, кто-то говорит, что можно обойтись и без нее, информации очень мало и не совсем понятно как это реализовать, точнее совсем непонятно.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov вы поможете?

Comment: I'm not sure that non-English posts are allowed here.  The topic looks too wide and too generic for single question.  Though, if you need assistance, feel free to contact me personally, my contacts are easy to find on Web.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This question is too wide and probably should be split into parts:

1. How to deal with Ethereum from within back-end application

   1.1. How to monitor Ethereum blockchain event effectively

   1.2. How to securely deal with private keys in back-end applications

   1.3. How to manage hard forks
2. How to implement ERC20 token deposits for users

   2.1. How to generate unique deposit addresses for users

   2.2. How to effectively collect tokens deposited by users from multiple addresses into single one

   2.3. How to track tokens deposited by users to guarantee that no deposit was missed and no deposit was processed twice
3. How to implement token withdrawals by users

   3.1. How to ensure that successful withdrawal transaction will not be reverted

   3.2. How to ensure that failed withdrawal transaction will not be finally executed

   3.3. How to track withdrawal transaction to guarantee that no withdrawal was missed and not withdrawal was processed twice
4. How to hold tokens on exchange

   4.1. How to hold tokens on multisig wallet

   4.2. How to hold tokens on paper wallet

   4.3. How to hold tokens on hardware wallet

   4.4. How to sign transaction on offline device

Each item is a search query you may want to perform on stackexchange or Google.

Comment: This is not really an answer even if you are trying to help the asker to find relevant information.

Comment: It is roadmap.  For questions as wide as this one, roadmap might be the answer.  And real detailed answer could be far too long to be posted on stackexchange.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov do u have a telegram?

Comment: Yes, @Mikhail_Vladimirov